# New Xamarin Forms 4.6 MediaElement not working for Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, mediaelement, xamarin-forms-4

I tried out the new Xamarin Forms 4.6.0.726 MediaElement control in a very simple Xamarin Forms Shell Project.
I added the MediaElement control in a ContentPage and set its properties (AutoPlay on true, IsLooping on true, Source on an mp4 file, ShowPlaybackControls on true).
I added also the Experimental-Flag for the MediaElement in the App.xaml.cs.

When I run the App, the video is played, with sound, image and player controls visible, on iOS, but it does not work on Android. 
On Android the player controls are not displayed, nothing happens.

Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Make sure that you had added permissions in Android project .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT - Do you mean the SetFlag MediaElement_Experimental in the MainActivity? I tried that already, does not make any difference. If you mean something else, please provide me some more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to check these,make sure you have stored a media file in the platform project.

On Android, media files must be stored in a subfolder of **Resources** named **raw**. The **raw** folder cannot contain subfolders. The media file must have a `Build Action` of `AndroidResource`.

[image]

then in your page.xaml (don't use layout to wrap `MediaElement`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MediaElementDemos.PlayAppPackageVideoResourcePage"
         Title="Play app package video resource">
    <MediaElement Source="ms-appx:///XamarinForms101UsingEmbeddedImages.mp4"
              ShowsPlaybackControls="True" IsLooping="True" AutoPlay="True" />
</ContentPage>
```

add `Device.SetFlags(new string[] { "MediaElement_Experimental" });` in your **App.xaml.cs**

```
public App()
    {
        Device.SetFlags(new string[] { "MediaElement_Experimental" });
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new PlayPage());
    }
```

**Update**:

If you want to play the mp4 from an URL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     x:Class="MediaElementDemos.PlayAppPackageVideoResourcePage"
     Title="Play app package video resource">
    <MediaElement Source="https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/5d93/a1eab4bf-3288-4faf-81c4-294402a85d93/XamarinShow_mid.mp4"
          ShowsPlaybackControls="True" IsLooping="True" AutoPlay="True" />
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I am not embedding my mp4 in the App, I am accessing the file from an URL. I already set the Experimental flag in the App.xaml.cs.

Comment: @DanielSimon I change the update above,if you want to play a file from an Url,you just need change the Source to your url.

Comment: Your solution works with your mp4 file, although the playback of the file starts pretty late. But it doesn't work with my mp4 file. I wait a few minutes, but nothing happens. The file is not broken, in iOS it works with no problems, the playback starts also a lot faster under iOS.

Comment: @DanielSimon You could try to use the url in my sample to see if it would work.

Comment: Please check this app -->https://github.com/devcrux/Xamarin.Forms-Shapes  ,I have done all the instructions provides.It works perectly in android 9 but not working with android 10.

Answer (score 1):

Something I had to add according to this article on top of the above answers to make it work : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9785

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {
                videoPlayer.Play();

                videoPlayer.ScaleTo(0.99f);
                videoPlayer.ScaleTo(1.00f);

                return false;
            });
```

Make sure you add the above answers prior adding this.